# WebClient DownloadString response with strange characters

Tags: json, vb.net, webclient

I am trying to use the Softaculous API within cpanel to do a few things. The result of the downloadstring is coming in as such:

"a:4:{s:5:""title"";s:31:""Softaculous - All Installations"";s:13:""installations"";a:1:{i:26;a:2:{s:8:""

This is just a small sample of the much longer string. I looked everywhere on the web to find a solution to this, but could not find one.

Is there something else I need to do before parsing with JSon because it is creating an exception "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Here is the code:

```
Dim auth As String = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(Convert.ToString(user & Convert.ToString(":")) & pwd))

        Dim webClient As New WebClient
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        Dim myWebHeaderCollection As WebHeaderCollection = webClient.ResponseHeaders

        webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth)

        Dim result = webClient.DownloadString("https://mywebsite.com:2083/frontend/paper_lantern/softaculous/index.live.php?&api=serialize&act=installations")
        Dim resultResponse As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mark Yes, this was the solution. I was able to find this shortly after posting, but forgot to post the answer. If you would like, you can post the answer and I will mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the response in JSON, instead of the PHP [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) format, use `api=json` instead of `api=serialize` in the URL.